# iPhone - check if internet connectivity is available or not

Tags: iphone

I am using the following code to find out whether internet connectivity is present or not.

```
struct sockaddr_in zeroAddress; 
bzero(&zeroAddress, sizeof(zeroAddress)); 
zeroAddress.sin_len = sizeof(zeroAddress); 
zeroAddress.sin_family = AF_INET;

// Recover reachability flags
SCNetworkReachabilityRef defaultRouteReachability = SCNetworkReachabilityCreateWithAddress(NULL, (struct sockaddr*)&zeroAddress); 
SCNetworkReachabilityFlags flags; 
BOOL didRetrieveFlags = SCNetworkReachabilityGetFlags(defaultRouteReachability, &flags); 
CFRelease(defaultRouteReachability); 
if (!didRetrieveFlags) { 
    NSLog(@"Error. Could not recover network reachability flags"); 
    return 0; 
} 
BOOL isReachable = flags & kSCNetworkFlagsReachable; 
BOOL needsConnection = flags & kSCNetworkFlagsConnectionRequired; 
return (isReachable && !needsConnection) ? YES : NO;
```

This method returns the expected result when my device is connected to a wifi network. But if I test the same method on a 3G or an Edge network, it returns a NO (i.e. not connected to the internet)

Any ideas why?

Thanks.

Comment: Is there a particular reason why you need to preflight this check? Apple's recommendation has been not to: just go ahead and try to talk to what you need to talk to, and be prepared to deal with reachability results. Network conditions on iPhone can be very very transitory.

Comment: I want to show different outputs based on different conditions - if there is an issue with the server, the message will be different, if no internet connection, it will again be different

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is you are not actively connected, the cellular modem is powered down (which it does after a few seconds of inactivity). Chances are if you look you you will see that needsConnection is YES. Any of the higher level APIs (CFNetwork, NSURLConnection) will cause the connection to be established automatically.

You can test to see if you have cellular available by checking for the kSCNetworkReachabilityFlagsIsWWAN key.

Answer (score 6):

Look through Apple's code sample called "Reachability", and look at the top of the comments for how to use it in asynchronous mode:

http://developer.apple.com/IPhone/library/samplecode/Reachability/index.html